# bind model including HttpPostedFile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have a class containing a property as HttpPostedFile

```
public class VehicleModel 
{

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public HttpPostedFile picture {get;set;}
}
```

when i want to generate a scaffolded item it tells me that HttpPostedFile doesn't have a key defined.

Please help !